Received an email “Review parameters blocked by Meta”
We have received an email about Meta ad account
1 Event parameters blocked
Hi ,
Some event parameters in your data,  Ad account’s Pixel(<pixel_id>) may contain information that goes against our Meta Business Tool Terms. The parameters are blocked. Review and fix the parameters. By addressing issues in the data you send us, you’re helping protect your users and your business.
Further issues can result in data restrictions and limited functionality in certain ad features such as custom conversions and custom audiences.
Blocked parameters – by Meta
These parameters must be removed from your integration setup.
subject
Learn more
Troubleshoot Meta Business Tools data policy violations
Why this happened
It looks like data in your event parameters may go against the Sharing Business Tool Data with Meta policy in our terms.
Examples of information you should not send to us include:
Health, financial or other categories of sensitive topics about people
Information from or about children under the age of 13
Customer information parameters that are not hashed as required by Meta
Identifiers such as social security numbers and credit card numbers

Thanks,
Meta Business Team”
Do you have any suggestion on why this happened.
I tried to get solution to debug and resolve event parameters blocked issue.
